Is there a way to prevent actions of the forward/backward keys on a mouse
I tried to find at least some information about which mouse events can be prevented with event.preventDefault for forward/backward actions.
Found only this example of code (works in chrome, but not firefox):


window.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
   if (e.button === 3 || e.button === 4)
      e.preventDefault();
});



Is there a standard or document that clearly defines in which event I can cancel the forward/backward actions of the side mouse keys?

I suspect that preventing default action for side mouse keys is not standardized and there is no event that can successfully apply for all browsers.
What do you think?

Is the listener function running in FF? Add a console.log call to confirm.

If it runs, use console.log(e.button) to see if this is being set.

@Barmar nay, in ff it doesn't work for forward/backward keys unfortunately. That's why I ask about standards and alternative solution if it is.

@Barmar If you press other mouse keys, then mouseup of course works, but not for the side keys. It feels like ff just doesn't support them.

Sounds like it's not treating them as mouse buttons, but something special, like linking them at a low level to the forward/back arrows in the toolbar.
